# How to prevent page breaks between bibliography sections

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, biblatex-chicago, widows-orphans

In my syllabus I have an extended bibliography subdivided into different thematic sections. There are a number of places where I'm left with extra blank space at the bottom of one section/page, and then it starts the next section on the next page, even though there would be room on the preceding page for the header and one or two entries. I assume this has to do with it wanting a minimum number of entries below the header—sort of an orphan problem for bib entries—but I don't know how to adjust this (if my diagnosis is even correct). How can I get the bibliography sections to run continuously?

In the MWE below, the goal would be to get 'Category 2' and the first Davidson entry (at least) to appear on page 1.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber,compresspages=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Bibliography}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\large{Category 1}}
\begin{refsection}\nocite{fawtier53,krynen87,ylouses91,cassard07,pocquet53,copy82,vaivre74,roblin09,bedosrezak93,beaune91} \printbibliography \end{refsection}
\vspace{-13pt}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\large{Category 2}}
\begin{refsection}\nocite{davidson94,rastall94,decoster02,moeglin10} \printbibliography \end{refsection}
\vspace{-13pt}

\end{document}
```

The called bib entries (for `biblio.bib`) are as follows:

```
author = {Decoster, Caroline},
title = {La Convocation à l'assemblée de 1302, instrument juridique au service de la propagande royale},
journal = {Parliaments, Estates and Representation},
volume = {22},
pages = {17–36},
date = {2002},
}

@article{fawtier53,
author = {Fawtier, Robert},
title = {Parlement d'Angleterre et États généraux de France au Moyen Âge},
journal = {Comptes rendus de l'Académie des inscriptions et belles-lettres},
volume = {30},
pages = {275–284},
date = {1953},
}

@article{krynen87,
author = {Krynen, Jacques},
title = {La Représentation politique dans l'ancienne France: l'expérience des États généraux},
journal = {Droits},
volume = {6},
pages = {31–44},
date = {1987},
}


@incollection{cassard07,
author = {Cassard, Jean-Christophe},
title = {Pairie de France et barons de Bretagne: plasticité et vacuité des mythes historico-politiques},
booktitle = {Vérité poétique, vérité médiévale: mythes, modèles et idéologies politiques au Moyen Âge},
editor = {Cassard, Jean-Christophe and Gaucher, Élisabeth and Kerhervé, Jean},
pages = {59–76},
date = {2007},
address = {Brest},
}

@article{ylouses91,
author = {Lefort des Ylouses, Emile},
title = {Le Sceau et le pouvoir: l'évolution du sceau des ducs de Bretagne, du XIIe siècle au XVe siècle},
journal = {Mémoires de la Société d'histoire et d'archéologie de Bretagne},
volume = {68},
pages = {129–140},
date = {1991},
}

@article{pocquet53,
author = {Pocquet du Haut-Jussé, B.-A.},
title = {Couronne fermée et cercle ducal en Bretagne},
journal = {Bulletin philologique et historique jusqu'à 1715 du Comité des travaux historiques et scientifiques, années 1951–1952},
pages = {103–112},
date = {1953},
}

@article{copy82,
author = {Copy, Jean-Yves},
title = {Du nouveau sur la couronne ducale bretonne: le témoignage des tombeaux},
journal = {Mémoires de la Société d'histoire et d'archéologie de Bretagne},
volume = {59},
pages = {171–194},
date = {1982},
}

@incollection{moeglin10,
author = {Moeglin, Jean-Marie},
title = {Entre 1250 et 1350: système des États et ordre dynastique},
booktitle = {Power and Persuasion: Essays on the Art of State Building in Honour of W. P. Blockmans},
editor = {Hoppenbrouwers, P. C. M. and Janse, A. and Stein, R.},
pages = {3–25},
date = {2010},
address = {Turnhout},
keywords = {secondary},
}

@article{vaivre74,
author = {de Vaivre, Jean-Bernard},
title = {Le Décor héraldique de la cassette d'Aix-la-Chapelle},
journal = {Aachener Kunstblätter},
volume = {45},
pages = {97–124},
date = {1974},
}

@book{roblin09,
editor = {Roblin, Vincent},
title = {Recueil des actes des vicomtes de Limoges, Xe–XIVe siècle},
date = {2009},
address = {Geneva},
}

@book{bedosrezak93,
author = {Bedos-Rezak, Brigitte},
title = {Form and Order in Medieval France: Studies in Social and Quantitative Sigillography},
date = {1993},
address = {Aldershot},
}

@book{beaune91,
author = {Beaune, Colette},
translator = {Huston, Susan Ross},
title = {The Birth of an Ideology: Myths and Symbols of Nation in Late-Medieval France},
date = {1991},
address = {Berkeley},
}

@incollection{rastall94,
author = {Rastall, Richard},
title = {The Musical Repertory},
pages = {162–196},
crossref = {davidson94},
}

@collection{davidson94,
editor = {Davidson, Clifford},
title = {The Iconography of Heaven},
date = {1994},
address = {Kalamazoo},
}
```

Edited to add a picture of the problem:
[image: Picture of pages 1 and 2, with a big gap at the bottom of page 1]

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't bother and I would even do away with the `\vspace{-13pt}` you have already. Keep in mind that not all space leading up to the page number in the footer is available for the text block. Plus, headings usually have space above and below them (the space above might be reduced/removed if the header starts on a new page) and you definitely do not want only the heading on the old page and the entries on the new page. Even heading and just the first entry might look a bit out of place.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you absolutely want the second category to start on the same page as the first?

Comment: Yes, because all the extra gaps in a long bibliography add up quite a bit in overall length. The actual formatting of my document is a bit more elegant than in the MWE above, of course!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With `[heading=subbibliography]` you achieve what you want

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber,compresspages=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Bibliography}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{westfahl:space,aksin,angenendt}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Category 1}]

\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{baez/article,bertram,doody}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Category 2}]
    
\end{refsection}
    
\end{document}
```

To force category 2 to stay on the same page without affecting the layout of your document, type `\enlargethispage*{3cm}`. This, however, may cause overflow of category 2 to the footer

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
    
@article{fawtier53,
    author = {Fawtier, Robert},
    title = {Parlement d'Angleterre et États généraux de France au Moyen Âge},
    journal = {Comptes rendus de l'Académie des inscriptions et belles-lettres},
    volume = {30},
    pages = {275–284},
    date = {1953},
}

@article{krynen87,
    author = {Krynen, Jacques},
    title = {La Représentation politique dans l'ancienne France: l'expérience des États généraux},
    journal = {Droits},
    volume = {6},
    pages = {31–44},
    date = {1987},
}

@incollection{cassard07,
    author = {Cassard, Jean-Christophe},
    title = {Pairie de France et barons de Bretagne: plasticité et vacuité des mythes historico-politiques},
    booktitle = {Vérité poétique, vérité médiévale: mythes, modèles et idéologies politiques au Moyen Âge},
    editor = {Cassard, Jean-Christophe and Gaucher, Élisabeth and Kerhervé, Jean},
    pages = {59–76},
    date = {2007},
    address = {Brest},
}

@article{ylouses91,
    author = {Lefort des Ylouses, Emile},
    title = {Le Sceau et le pouvoir: l'évolution du sceau des ducs de Bretagne, du XIIe siècle au XVe siècle},
    journal = {Mémoires de la Société d'histoire et d'archéologie de Bretagne},
    volume = {68},
    pages = {129–140},
    date = {1991},
}

@article{pocquet53,
    author = {Pocquet du Haut-Jussé, B.-A.},
    title = {Couronne fermée et cercle ducal en Bretagne},
    journal = {Bulletin philologique et historique jusqu'à 1715 du Comité des travaux historiques et scientifiques, années 1951–1952},
    pages = {103–112},
    date = {1953},
}

@article{copy82,
    author = {Copy, Jean-Yves},
    title = {Du nouveau sur la couronne ducale bretonne: le témoignage des tombeaux},
    journal = {Mémoires de la Société d'histoire et d'archéologie de Bretagne},
    volume = {59},
    pages = {171–194},
    date = {1982},
}

@incollection{moeglin10,
    author = {Moeglin, Jean-Marie},
    title = {Entre 1250 et 1350: système des États et ordre dynastique},
    booktitle = {Power and Persuasion: Essays on the Art of State Building in Honour of W. P. Blockmans},
    editor = {Hoppenbrouwers, P. C. M. and Janse, A. and Stein, R.},
    pages = {3–25},
    date = {2010},
    address = {Turnhout},
    keywords = {secondary},
}

@article{vaivre74,
    author = {de Vaivre, Jean-Bernard},
    title = {Le Décor héraldique de la cassette d'Aix-la-Chapelle},
    journal = {Aachener Kunstblätter},
    volume = {45},
    pages = {97–124},
    date = {1974},
}

@book{roblin09,
    editor = {Roblin, Vincent},
    title = {Recueil des actes des vicomtes de Limoges, Xe–XIVe siècle},
    date = {2009},
    address = {Geneva},
}

@book{bedosrezak93,
    author = {Bedos-Rezak, Brigitte},
    title = {Form and Order in Medieval France: Studies in Social and Quantitative Sigillography},
    date = {1993},
    address = {Aldershot},
}

@book{beaune91,
    author = {Beaune, Colette},
    translator = {Huston, Susan Ross},
    title = {The Birth of an Ideology: Myths and Symbols of Nation in Late-Medieval France},
    date = {1991},
    address = {Berkeley},
}

@incollection{rastall94,
    author = {Rastall, Richard},
    title = {The Musical Repertory},
    pages = {162–196},
    crossref = {davidson94},
}

@collection{davidson94,
    editor = {Davidson, Clifford},
    title = {The Iconography of Heaven},
    date = {1994},
    address = {Kalamazoo},
}

@article{angenendt,
    author       = {Angenendt, Arnold},
    title        = {In Honore Salvatoris~-- Vom Sinn und Unsinn der
        Patrozinienkunde},
    journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
    date         = 2002,
    volume       = 97,
    pages        = {431--456, 791--823},
    langid       = {german},
    indextitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
    shorttitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
    annotation   = {A German article in a French journal. Apart from that, a
        typical \texttt{article} entry. Note the \texttt{indextitle}
        field},
}

@article{baez/article,
    author       = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
    title        = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra {V}: 2-Groups},
    journaltitle = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
    date         = 2004,
    volume       = 12,
    pages        = {423-491},
    version      = 3,
    eprint       = {math/0307200v3},
    eprinttype   = {arxiv},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} with \texttt{eprint} and
        \texttt{eprinttype} fields. Note that the arXiv reference is
        transformed into a clickable link if \texttt{hyperref} support
        has been enabled.  Compare \texttt{baez\slash online}, which
        is the same item given as an \texttt{online} entry},
}

@article{bertram,
    author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
    title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces},
    date         = 1996,
    volume       = 9,
    number       = 2,
    pages        = {529-571},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{volume} and a
        \texttt{number} field},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=biber, compresspages=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\section{Bibliography}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Category 1}]

\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
    
    \enlargethispage*{3cm}
    
    \nocite{davidson94,rastall94,moeglin10}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Category 2}]
    
\end{refsection}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've implemented these changes, but they don't seem make any difference to the spacing in the bibliography in my MWE—when the first category takes up most of the page, the second category is still pushed onto the next page. (Still, it's useful to know about the more streamlined code for the same effect!)

Comment: This is about how the document class handles inserting white spaces. You must then modify your code above to replicate your issue

Comment: My code does replicate the error, but for some reason your margins are different (there is more text per line), so the bibliography when you compile isn't long enough in section 1 to show the problem. I've added a picture to the original post to illustrate the issue.